# why the text is not display in angular?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-template, angular2-directives

I am trying to display component text in angular 2 .but it is not display .could you please tell me where I am doing wrong ?
here is my code

http://plnkr.co/edit/PrWxwf3wT5COVxRwIpqX?p=preview

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.0/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/tools/system.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/tools/typescript.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.0/Rx.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.0/angular2.dev.js"></script>

    <script>
      System.config({
        transpiler: 'typescript', 
        typescriptOptions: { emitDecoratorMetadata: true }, 
        packages: {'gg': {defaultExtension: 'tp'}} 
      });
      System.import('boot')
            .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <my-app>Loading...</my-app>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: .tp  extenstion ? is this mistypes with .ts or realy it is .tp ?

Comment: i take .tp ...not by mistake

Comment: ohh i don't know about .tp extension sry.

Comment: You don't have an "app" or a "gg" package, you are looking for boot in root, yet adding the default extension 'tp' to the app package, move your boot.tp file in a gg folder if you are using this example, or an app folder if you are doing it like in the plunker

Comment: please provide plunker ..or best way to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don't have a folder (package), you can specify your extensions explicitly.

```
  System.import('boot.tp')
        .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
```

And

```
   import { AppComponent } from './script.tp'
```